# How to handle anchor with download attribute and HTTP 404 - Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, download, anchor

I'm using the download attribute on an anchor (link).

In some rare cases, I know that I'll have a 404 error (file not found).

Chromium based browsers handle it by showing a `Download failed - No file` in the download pane. This seems right to me.

Firefox on the other hand, does not show any error message and only opens a blank 'New tab'.

**Is this a normal Firefox behavior? I this a Firefox bug ? Am I doing it wrong ?**

---

- In the case of a non-200 HTTP code, I would like the user to be informed
- If possible, I would like to avoid the use of JS
- The download URL (href) is on the same domain to comply with the `same-origin` policy.
- Here is an CodePen example (don't run on stackoverflow snipet for same-origin policy) : https://codepen.io/random-bytes/pen/xxBLdYr

Comment: Hmm, I also see in FF that clicking the link itself opens an émpty tab', but opening it with rightmouse and then "open link in new tab" gives a nice 404 from Codepen. I don't know why that happens.